# Insure that regex moves to the second OR element only if the first one doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a certain word on a string and only if it doesn't exist i want to match the another one using the OR `|` operator ....but the match is ignoring that... how can i insure that the behavior works :

```js
const str = 'Soraka is an ambulance 911'
const regex = RegExp('('+'911'+'|'+'soraka'+')','i')
console.log(str.match(regex)[0])     // should get 911 instead
```

Comment: The regex matching works through the string from the beginning to the end, character by character. If you want to prioritize the matches as per your description, you'll have to use more than one regex and attempt the matches separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`911` occurs late in the string, whereas `Soraka` occurs earlier, and the regex engine iterates character-by-character, so `Soraka` gets matched first, even though it's on the right-hand side of the alternation.

One option would be to match `Soraka` or `911` in captured lookaheads instead, and then with the regex match object, alternate between the two groups to get the one which is not `undefined`:

```js
const check = (str) => {
  const regex = /^(?=.*(911)|.*(Soraka))/;
  const match = str.match(regex);
  console.log(match[1] || match[2]);
};

check('Soraka is an ambulance 911');
check('foo 911');
check('foo Soraka');
```

Comment: This is super clever.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `includes` and `find`

- You can pass the strings in the priority sequence, so as soon as `find` found any string in the original string it returns that strings back,

```js
const str = 'Soraka is an ambulance 911'

const findStr = (...arg) => {
  return [...arg].find(toCheck => str.includes(toCheck))
}

console.log(findStr("911", "Soraka"))
```

You can extend the `findStr` if you want your match to be case insensitive something like this

```js
const str = 'Soraka is an ambulance 911'

const findStr = (...arg) => {
  return [...arg].find(toCheck => str.toLowerCase().includes(toCheck.toLowerCase()))
}

console.log(findStr("Soraka", "911"))
```

If you want match to be whole word not the partial words than you can build dynamic regex and use it search value

```js
const str = '911234 Soraka is an ambulance 911'

const findStr = (...arg) => {
  return [...arg].find(toCheck =>{
    let regex = new RegExp(`\\b${toCheck}\\b`,'i')
    return regex.test(str)
  })
}

console.log(findStr("911", "Soraka"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a greedy dot before a capturing group that matches `911` or `Soraka`:

```
/.*(911)|(Soraka)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xyx65M/2)

**The `.*`** (or, if there are line breaks, use `/.*(911)|(Soraka)/s` in Chrome/Node, or `/[^]*(911)|(Soraka)/` to support legacy EMCMScript versions) will **ensure the regex index advances to the rightmost position when matching `911` or `Soraka`**.

JS demo (borrowed from [@CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57751632/3832970)'s answer):

```js
const check = (str) => {
  const regex = /.*(911)|(Soraka)/;
  const match = str.match(regex) || ["","NO MATCH","NO MATCH"];
  console.log(match[1] || match[2]);
};

check('Soraka is an ambulance 911');
check('Ambulance 911, Soraka');
check('foo 911');
check('foo Soraka');
check('foo oops!');
```

Comment: Note that `String.match` will only return the first match here as the regex has no `g` modifier that is why it works.